# SASS cannot watch scss, using [--watch]

Tags: sass

I made a standard installation of SASS (Dart Sass 1.16.1), following instructions: https://sass-lang.com/install.

**My setup:**

node -v : v11.6.0

sass --version: 1.16.0

OS: Ubuntu linux 18.04 LTE.

---

SASS installation:

```
npm install -g sass
```

**Process flow:**

First creation of CSS from SCSS:

```
sass index.scss index.css
```

Attemt to start [--watch]: (the both files are located in same folder):

```
sass --no-source-map --watch index.scss index.css
```

Also tried with colon [:] between file names, which actually is only required when specifying folders:

```
sass --no-source-map --watch index.scss:index.css
```

After activating the watch, I change something [color: red;] to [color: blue], but css is not update when saving scss.

Terminal printout after running [--watch]: None.

**My SCSS file:**

```
$color: blue;

.div-1 {
  background-color: $color;
}
```

**The CSS result without running [--watch]:**

```
.div-1 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want no source map? It works for me without that flag.

Comment: Recently started with SASS and i just wanted to reduce the amount of produced files, that's the simle reason of exluding sourcemap. I tried to remove the [--no-source-map], but it does not improve the result. Still no [--watch] monitoring, and no confirmation printout in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I Think the problem might be, that you need to use `:` between the input and the output.

`sass --no-source-map --watch index.scss:index.css`

Reference is here:
https://sass-lang.com/guide

Comment: updated the question info. I actually already tested with [:] between files, even though it is only required when specifying folders.

Comment: So you don't have any feedback from the terminal?

Update: 
Do you have @imports in your `index.scss`? Maybe the changed SCSS file isn't imported in the `index.scss`

Comment: Updated the questions. No feedback from terminal.If I run the [--watch] command without initially having the result css-file, the css files is not being created (maybe normal?). If I make sure the css does exist prior to run [--watch] I get no confirmation printout, but no errors.

Comment: Do you know if the are restriction of where one needs to be in the folder/file structure for [--watch] to work?

Comment: If you start this comment without `--watch` it creates the files?